# Passing variables to a function with CreateRemoteThread

Tags: c++, winapi

```
HANDLE CreateRemoteThread(
  HANDLE                 hProcess,
  LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES  lpThreadAttributes,
  SIZE_T                 dwStackSize,
  LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE lpStartAddress,
  LPVOID                 lpParameter,
  DWORD                  dwCreationFlags,
  LPDWORD                lpThreadId
);
```

> lpParameter
>
> A pointer to a variable to be passed to the thread function.

```
int x = 0;
LPCWSTR foo = L"Hello World";

CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, 0, 0, pFunction, &x, 0, 0);
```

Suppose i need to pass more than one variable, like `x` and `foo`, to a function that requires two parameters, `example`:

```
LPCWSTR Test(int x, LPCWSTR foo) 
{
  //....
}
```

How would it be?

Comment: You can't (directly) call a function that requires two parameters with `CreateThread` or `CreateRemoteThread`.  The thread procedure MUST match the correct signature and accept exactly one pointer.  The one pointer parameter can point at any amount of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As its name implies, `CreateRemoteThread()` creates a new thread in an external process.  As such, the `lpStartAddress` parameter must point to the memory address of a function in the target process, and the `lpParameter` parameter must point to a memory address that exists in the target process (unless it is a pointer-casted integer).  You can't pass a pointer to memory that exists locally in the process that is calling `CreateRemoteThread()`.  You can use `VirtualAllocEx()` to allocate memory in another process, eg:

```cpp
DWORD WINAPI MyThreadProc(LPVOID lpParameter)
{
    INT *x = (INT*) lpParameter;
    // use *x as needed...
    VirtualFree(x, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
    return 0;
}

...

LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE pFunction = ...; // point to MyThreadProc() in hProcess

INT x = 0;

LPVOID param = VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, NULL, sizeof(x), MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);
if (!param) ...

SIZE_T numWritten;
if (!WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, param, &x, sizeof(x), &numWritten)) ...

if (!CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, 0, 0, pFunction, param, 0, 0)) ...
```

Alternatively, you can use a pointer-casted integer instead, in which case you don't need to allocate anything:

```cpp
DWORD WINAPI MyThreadProc(LPVOID lpParameter)
{
    INT x = INT(reinterpret_cast<INT_PTR>(lpParameter));
    // use x as needed...
    return 0;
}

...

LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE pFunction = ...; // point to MyThreadProc() in hProcess

int x = 0;
LPVOID param = reinterpret_cast<LPVOID>(INT_PTR(x));

if (!CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, 0, 0, pFunction, param, 0, 0)) ...
```

If you need to pass multiple values to the function, you will have to allocate a `struct` in the target process to hold them, eg:

```cpp
#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct MyThreadData
{
    INT x;
    LPCWSTR foo; // points to fooData...
    //WCHAR fooData[]...
}; 
#pragma pack(pop)

...

DWORD WINAPI MyThreadProc(LPVOID lpParameter)
{
    MyThreadData *params = static_cast<MyThreadData*>(lpParameter);
    // use params->x and params->foo as needed...
    VirtualFree(params, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
    return 0;
}

...

LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE pFunction = ...; // point to MyThreadProc() in hProcess

INT x = 0;
LPCWSTR foo = L"Hello World";
int foo_numBytes = (lstrlenW(foo) + 1) * sizeof(WCHAR);

MyThreadData *params = static_cast<MyThreadData*>(VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, NULL, sizeof(MyThreadData) + fooNumBytes, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE));
if (!params) ...

SIZE_T numWritten;
if (!WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, &(params->x), &x, sizeof(x), &numWritten)) ...

LPWSTR foo_data = reinterpret_cast<LPWSTR>(params + 1);
if (!WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, &(params->foo), &foo_data, sizeof(foo_data), &numWritten)) ...

if (!WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, fooDataPtr, foo, foo_numBytes, &numWritten)) ...

CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, 0, 0, pFunction, params, 0, 0);
```

Comment: How does the function receiving the struct handle these parameters?

Comment: @D2rake Exactly as I showed. Is there something unclear about it?